# Manage engine MDM misbehaving

Tags: mdm

We currently use Manage engine for our MDM,

We are having issues (only in the past 1-2months) that our newly deployed **Android** phones cant use their active sync profile to log in to outlook and teams.

When logging in they are advised that the mobile is not a managed device and the device needs to be enrolled before they can access company data.

The devices are showing as fully enrolled on manage engine and no compliance issues showing on the mobile in the ME-MDM app.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this issue?

The device is enrolled using token enrollment, previous issues have been related to the phone not pulling activesync profiles which is usually resolved by assigning the phone to a different user and then back to the designated user. this has no effect on the current problem.

historicly enrolled phones have no issue currently. only newly provisioned phones.

we have been in contact with Manage engine support and they have been next to useless and advise that everyhting is as is should be, but we are still having this issue.